# How many mangalitsa pigs can live on an acre of field?

Tags: pigs

I'm looking at ordering [mangalitsa pigs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangalica) for some land, and was wondering how many I can keep on an acre with rotating pasture system.

Comment: Ask the [Hungarian National Association of Mangalica Breeders](http://www.mangalicatenyesztok.hu/index-english.html) or [farmers keeping them](https://bealsfarmcharcuterie.com/pages/bealsfarm-mangalitzas)?

Answer (score 3):

These quotes from the [Appendix - Pig Production Case Studies](http://www.fao.org/fileadmin/user_upload/animalwelfare/gap_pig_case_studies.pdf) (page 137 and up) of the report "Animal Welfare Aspects of Good Agricultural Practice:
pig production" may give you an idea:

- Ökorex Bio Kft. in Fiad, Hungary keeps *60 sows and their progeny which occupy an area of about 5 hectares*
- On Primagro Bt, in Kozárd, Hungary *the sows are kept in groups of 45. They share large paddocks measuring 4 hectares with open straw-bedded huts*
- Dél-Cserháti Ökológiai Tájközpont Kht, in Jákotpuszta, Hungary has *3 boars, 80 sows plus all their progeny*:

> In winter, they are kept in a smaller paddock of about 30 hectares. In spring, the pigs are moved to larger paddocks
>   measuring about 70 hectares. In these paddocks, the animals feed on whatever is being grown in the fields. They receive no other food ration.

There are also more general publications like [Review of Production, Husbandry and Sustainability of Free-range Pig Production Systems](http://www.ajas.info/upload/pdf/17_262.pdf) (Z. H. Miao, P. C. Glatz and Y. J. Ru).

BTW I found all these Googling for [mangalica pigs husbandry density acre](https://www.google.nl/search?q=mangalica+pigs+husbandry+density+acre), so it looks as if you just need to spend some more time browsing the Internet.

And as I suggested in my comments, what's wrong with actually contacting farmers or associations like the [Hungarian National Association of Mangalica Breeders](http://www.mangalicatenyesztok.hu/index-english.html), and asking them?
You have a greater chance of getting answers that way than betting on Mangalica farmers reading this site.

Comment: I can't read the link you shared from https://www.google.nl/search?q=mangalica+pigs+husbandry+density+acre and some other stuff in hungarian.

Comment: That is a Google search. What's the issue - it will present you search results in English. I don't read Hungarian either and I'm not willing to hold your hand.